# Parsing JSON to a recyclerview not Displaying

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm doing an app that gets the nearby locations using JSON and displays them in a recyclerview. My problem is that, I'm really not sure what am I doing wrong here cause everything looks pretty well.

This is my code for reading JSON:

private void loadRecyclerViewData() {

```
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data ...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLDATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            List_Item item = new List_Item(o.getString("name"), o.getString("reference"));
                            listItems.add(item);
                            System.out.println("My List Item: " + listItems);

                        }

                        adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

and this is my JSON structure:

[image: JSON structure]

This is my stackTrace:[image: StackTace]

Comment: define your recycler View and adapter before the request and in your request use adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: Thanks @Assem, it's working now, I guess I needed that one line of code ...

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You should set layout manager.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
reycyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: This is what I how I did my Recyclerview setting: recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace too.